# date-fns/parse Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm trying to parse a Date String, using date-fns library,
I am passing the string date, the format and the date object to the parse method
But I am getting `Invalid Date` issue

I feel the issue is with the format I am using

**Following is the code I am trying -**

```
var parse = require("date-fns/parse");

console.log(
  parse("2020-12-20T11:12:58Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx", new Date())
);
```

I also tried `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Why do you use the trailing `.SSSxxx` in your format as it does not seem to map to the date you provide? The following format works fine against your date string `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`